# Is it possible to give a custom path to the `/static` directory using React and Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

## Edit

To anyone coming here in the future, I solved this problem by indicating a value for `PUBLIC_URL` in my `.env` file.

In my case, I set `PUBLIC_URL=/ui` and now the static assets are being served from `.../ui/static/...`

---

Whenever I build my app and launch it, the browser requests content from the static directory, such as this:

[image: img]

Is it possible to somehow change this? I took a look [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), but I didn't have any luck. I tried different combinations of `express.static(. . .)` to no avail.

Instead of http:///static/bundle123, I want it to request http:///custom/static/bundle123.

I've tried moving my `build/static` directory into `build/custom/static` and doing something like this, but it didn't work:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './custom')))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out the solution was really simple

Answer (score 0):

The first argument determines the URL path and the second part determines where the files are located on the file system.

So if your static files are located in the `public` directory (or in sub directories) and you want to access then on the `https://.../static` URL, you can use:

```js
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In your case, assuming you run the server from the `build` directory, using the following should work:

```
app.use('/custom/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

Now if you request an URL `https:///custom/static/foo` Express will look for a file named `foo` in the `static` folder.